# How to find an example of matrix $A$ that satisfies $A^{-1} = \frac{1}{n} A$, where $A = [a_{ij}]_{n \times n}$?

Tags: matrices

How to find an example of matrix $A$ that satisfies $A^{-1} = \frac{1}{n} A$, where $A \in n \times n$?
For example if $A= \left(
  \begin{array}{ccc}
   1 & 1 & 1\\
   1 & i & i^2\\
    1 & i^2 & i^4 \\
  \end{array}
\right)$,
then $A^{-1}=\frac{1}{3} \overline{A} $

Comment: Hint: if $A$ is the diagonal matrix $\alpha I$, what is $A^{-1}$?

Comment: You said "$A\in n\times n$". I have never seen notations like this. Did you mean $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, or its entries are positive integers in $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, or something else?

Comment: I meant that $A = [a_{ij}]_{n \times n}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your matrix satisfies the polynomial $A^2 - nI = 0$. Therefore the minimal polynomial of your matrix is either $A \pm \sqrt{n}I = 0$ where the only matrices which satisfy the criteria are $A=\pm\sqrt{n}I$ or the minimal polynomial splits as $(A+\sqrt{n}I)(A-\sqrt{n}I) = 0$. In this case, you can take any matrix similar to a diagonal matrix with $\pm\sqrt{n}$ on the diagonals.

Comment: followup question: give counterexample that $AA = A^2$( $A \in n \times n$)

Comment: @alvoutila: What is AA?

Comment: $AA=A \cdot A$ where $\cdot$ is matrix product.

Comment: $AA$ is always $A^2$. $A^2$ is shorthand for $AA$ so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: to me $A^2= \left(
  \begin{array}{ccc}
   1^2 & 1^2 & 1^2\\
   1^2 & i^2 & i^4\\
    1^2 & i^4 & i^8 \\
  \end{array}
\right) \neq A \cdot A $.

Comment: Ok, please do not re-define existing notation without at least telling us what it means. There is no one who could've possibly guessed what you wanted $A^2$ to be. If you want your $"A^2"$ to equal $A$, then each entry needs to satisfy $a^2 = a$. Each entry therefore needs to be $0$ or $1$.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to let $A$ be a multiple of the identity.  These are easy to invert.

Answer (score 1):

Hadamard matrices all have this property.